# "The 'prepublish' script failed with status code 34"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, web-deployment, asp.net-core-mvc

I can successfully build and run my project both in Debug and Release mode.

However when I want to publish to a server shared folder or just a local folder I get the following error in my console.

> "The 'prepublish' script failed with status code 34"

I am using Visual Studio 2015 update 1. ASP.NET 5 RC 1 Update 1

Here are my publish options

[image]

Both the 32 bit and 64 bit options gives the same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I removed the following section from my `project.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
 }
```

Since I'm on a corporate proxy those `npm` and `gulp` installs failing would block the publishing of the project

Comment: I remove that section too but not sure why it is failing

Comment: Thank you for your solution :)