# Publish MVC 6 Project as an artifact from TFS 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, tfs-2015

I've create a MVC 6 application which I can publish manually to IIS by copying the published files. I am now however trying to automate this in TFS 2015 so I can use it with Release Manager.

I've created a build that builds the solution but I can find the output location to publish the artifacts. I've tried adding OutputPath as a property but it seems to package the mvc app into nuget packages. Is there a command line switch to stop this?

Comment: Do you have a Publish Artifact step in your build definition?

Comment: Yes I do. It is publishing the content of the OutputPath folder I added but I'm trying to stop msbuild creating nuget packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now got this working by doing the following:

On the Visual Studio Build Task I added the following MSBuild Arguments:

/p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=ProfileName

I then had to remove prepublish script from the project.json

[the-prepublish-script-failed-with-status-code-34](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35620928/the-prepublish-script-failed-with-status-code-34)

I then added a Copy files task to copy from

/Release/PublishOutput to $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

And finally I could publish the artifact for use in Release Management

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [Copy Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/steps/utility/copy-files) step to only copy the OutputPath folder:

[image]

Comment: I'm struggling to generate the output from the build using the publish profile. If I run it from within VS, I get a new folder called PublishedOutput with approot, logs and wwwroot in it. I suspect these must be a combination of MSBuild Argument switches on the Visual Studio Build step.